# Make GUI.Box stay for 3 seconds

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a project in Unity using C# scripting. The GUI.Box will appear at the top the screen. The box will disappear when the player leaves the spot. How can I make the box stay there for an additional 3 seconds after the player leaves the designated spot?

Danpe's code corrected (working code):

```
bool shown = false;

void OnGUI () {
if (car.transform.position.y>=43 && car.transform.position.y<=44)
{
    shown = true;
}
else if (shown)
{
    StartCoroutine(DisapearBoxAfter(3.0f)); 
}
if(shown) 
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width/2)-200,0,400,30) , "King of the hill");
}
}

IEnumerator DisapearBoxAfter(float waitTime) { 
// suspend execution for waitTime seconds
yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
shown = false;
}




void Update () {
    OnGUI ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool shown = false;

void OnGUI () {
    if (car.transform.position.y>=43 && car.transform.position.y<=44)
    {
        shown = true;
    }
    else if (shown)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DisapearBoxAfter(3.0)); 
    }
    if(shown) {
        GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width/2)-200,0,400,30) , "King of the hill");
    }
}

IEnumerator DisapearBoxAfter(float waitTime) {
    // suspend execution for waitTime seconds
    return yield WaitForSeconds (waitTime);
    shown = false;
}


void Update () {
    OnGUI ();
}
```

Comment: Hi Danpe,
Thank you for your quick response. The code you provided had a few errors which I corrected using the debugger and it now works. Thank you so much. I am going to provide the working code in my question.

Comment: Hey, np i'm glad to help because i encountered this problem not long time ago :)
Anyway if it answeres your question you can tick my it as the right answer for the question by ticking the V.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Start ()
{
    ShowBox ();
}

function ShowBox ()
{
    // show label
    show = true;

    // cancel invoking method if already set to call after 3 seconds
    CancelInvoke("HideBox");

    // will call HideBox () after 3 sec
    Invoke ("HideBox", 3.0F);
}

function HideBox ()
{
   // dont show label
   show = false;
}

function Update ()
{
     if (car.transform.position.y>=43 && car.transform.position.y<=44)
     {
         ShowBox ();
     }
}

function OnGUI ()
{
     if(shown) 
     {
          GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width/2)-200,0,400,30) , "King of the hill");
     }
}
```